# Стиль выбора текста Window Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Решил я как-то начать изучать C# вместе с Window Forms и первым делом я решил опробовать сделать ввод "кода" как во всяких IDE. Понял, что для подобного хорошо подходит `RichTextBox` и при каждом нажатии кнопки при сфокусированном `RichTextBox` срабатывает `onTextChanged`, в котором каждый раз по новой проверяется текст для раскраски текста.

Вопрос:
Можно ли как-то изменить стиль выделения текста (который с синим фоном и белым текстом), у меня поле для ввода имеет черный фон и зелёный текст и такой выбор текста сильно выделяется особенно видно это при кратковременной перекраски текста.

IDE: Microsoft visual studio 2010
Проект: Windows Forms Application (C#)

Comment: Смотрите свойства `SelectionColor`, `SelectionBackColor` и другие свойства, в которых есть `Selection`.

Comment: Используя свойства ричтекстбокса не получится добиться высокой производительности. Нужно либо работать с ним низкоуровнево (давно забытое искусство, я даже забыл название библиотеки и не могу нагуглить).

Comment: Лучше используйте [FastColoredTextBox](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox) или [ScintillaNET](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET)

Comment: Текстовый процессор намного сложнее RichTextbox. Поэкспериментируйте лучше с браузерами там html css, за одно и его изучите

Comment: @Aziz Umarov я наоборот переехал с HTML так как там сложнее как по мне сделать подсветку текста

Comment: @ZEkA10000 поверьте мне вы не правы. И если для вас сложно html то но коммент

Comment: @aziz-umarov я встал там постоянно ровнять 2 объекта, так как в текстовом поле можно было делать только 1 цвет на весь текст, я делал поле ввода полностью прозрачное и поверх ставил <pre>

Comment: Teg code вам очки нибудь говорит?

Comment: code не поле для ввода текста и без подсветки текста, и как я понял code это кастрированный pre

Comment: @Alexander Petrov а есть где-нибудь инструкция внедрения fastTextBox в проект?

Comment: Подключаете nuget-пакет. Используете.